# Center 2 widgets within div

Tags: html, center

I have a problem on my responsive homepage. When the page is less than 1024px wide, I want the two contents widgets below each other and horizontally aligned. I defined their width and tried to center them with `margin: 0 auto`, but they stay at the left.

This is the link: http://readyforsolutions.be/wordpress/

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="home-left">
    <h1 class="widgettitle">Title</h1>
    <p>Text</p>
    <div class="homebuttonbox"><a class="homebutton"  href="http://readyforsolutions.be/wordpress/logistieke-problemen-quick-scan/">Doe de Quick     Scan</a></div>
</div>

<div class="home-right">
    <h1 class="widgettitle">Title</h1>
    <p>Text</p>
    <div class="homebuttonbox"><a class="homebutton" href="http://readyforsolutions.be/wordpress/logistieke-problemen-quick-scan/">Doe de Quick Scan</a></div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.entry-content {
    width: 100%;
}

.home-left {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.home-right {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 120px;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Stefaan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the display and margin parameters of the container `DIV` tag may do the trick:

**HTML:**

> ```
> <DIV class="entry-content">
>
> <div class="home-left">
>   <h1 class="widgettitle">Title #1</h1>
>   <p>Text</p>
>   <div class="homebuttonbox">Content Box #1</div>
> </div>
>
> <div class="home-right">
>   <h1 class="widgettitle">Title #2</h1>
>   <p>Text</p>
>   <div class="homebuttonbox">Content Box #2</div>
> </div>
>
> </DIV>
> ```

**CSS:**

> ```
> .entry-content {
>      margin-left: auto;
>      margin-right: auto;
>      border: 5px black solid;
>      text-align: center; }
>
> .home-left {
>      float: none;
>      margin: 0 auto;
>      border: 1px red solid;
>      display: inline-block;
>      text-align: left; 
> }
>
> .home-right {
>      float: none;
>      margin-left: 0px;
>      border: 1px blue solid;
>      display: inline-block;
>      text-align: left;
> }
> ```

Other Resource:
[CSS Centering](http://www.bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html)

Example:
[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/sparebrain/pen/xjChp)